# css media queries element moves to the left

Tags: css

I have a website where people write a message, once you click on the message the message appears on another page where people can comment under it. The second page where the message appears works fine on my monitor with a resolution of 1920 X 1380. However when I move the website to my laptop with a screen resolution of 1366 x 768 the message box that has a margin of auto moves to the left.

The message box has a class of comment

I tried this media query but nothing happened

```
@media(max-width: 1400px) {
  .comment {
    margin-left: 400px;  
  }
}


  My css for the comment box  

      .comment {
       margin:auto;
       border:1px solid #eaeaea;
       font-size: 14px;
       line-spacing: 2px;
       letter-spacing: 1.5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-style: verdana;
        }
```

Comment: We need to see the rest of your CSS in order to understand the issue

Comment: Could you please setup demo on JSFIDDLE? It would be easier to understand by this way.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your media query is before your standard declaration, it should be after to prevent overwriting. 
But If you want a dynamic margin  I recomend to calculate it with js getting the window's innerwidth and then apply it. You can use jQuery and its .css() method